# Django model CharField choice clashes with itself

Tags: django, django-models

I was extending my `Survey` model with `models.CharField(choices)` but I cannot due to

Error: `surveys.Survey.status: (models.E006) The field 'status' clashes with the field 'status' from model 'surveys.survey'.`

My Model Code:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    finish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, editable=False, db_index=True, default=uuid.uuid4)

    Finished = 'FI'
    OnProgress = 'OP'
    ReportGenerated = 'RG'
    STATUSES = [
        (Finished, 'Finished'),
        (OnProgress, 'OnProgress'),
        (ReportGenerated, 'ReportGenerated')
    ]
    status = response = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=STATUSES,
        default=OnProgress,
    )
```

Other models there I used Survey in case it may help:

```
class SurveyCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class SurveyQuestion(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response_explanation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    Not_Responded = 'NR'
    Fully_Implemented = 'FI'
    Partially_Implemented = 'PI'
    Not_Implemented = 'NI'
    SURVEY_RESPONSE_CHOICE = [
        (Not_Responded, 'Not Responded'),
        (Fully_Implemented, 'Fully Implemented'),
        (Partially_Implemented, 'Partially Implemented'),
        (Not_Implemented, ' Not Implemented'),
    ]
    response = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=SURVEY_RESPONSE_CHOICE,
        default=Not_Responded,
    )
```

Comment: Have you inherited Survey anywhere? or a One To One relationship with it?

Comment: Hey, I have used `User` as one-to-one to `UserProfile` model. I will update the question. But I haven't used Survey as One-to-one

Comment: No not between User and UserProfile. between Survey and any other model. Do you have a model named Status by any chance?

Comment: No, there is no such model named `Status`, I changed `STATUSES` to `SOME_DATA`, It has same error: `surveys.Survey.some_data: (models.E006) The field 'some_data' clashes with the field 'some_data' from model 'surveys.survey'.`

Comment: Also, I changed the field from `status` to `some_data`, error as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written:

```
status = response = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=STATUSES,
    default=OnProgress,
)
```

Note the `status = response =` here, this is causing issues. Keep it either as:

```
status = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=STATUSES,
    default=OnProgress,
)
```

Or:

```
response = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=STATUSES,
    default=OnProgress,
)
```

Comment: Oh sorry, now it is great

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `status = response = models.CharField()`. Try use only `status = models.CharField()`. If you want the same value for response to store on database, then you can do that overriding save() method.
for example:

```
status = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=STATUSES,
    default=OnProgress,
)
response = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=STATUSES,
    default=OnProgress,
    blank=True,
    null=True
)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.response = self.status
    super(Survey, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```